# Adafruit ServoHat importing PWM object

Tags: pwm, servo, adafruit

I am following the Adafruit page regarding the ServoHat for the Raspberry Pi. I am unclear what module to import to get the PWM class. This is the page about using the PWM class: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-16-channel-pwm-servo-hat-for-raspberry-pi/library-reference

They begin by running `pwm = PWM(0x40)`. However, they don't specify what to import in order to get the `PWM` class. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Run python in a shell (type python followed by return).  Then import the Adafruit modules one by one.  Use help(module name) to find the one which has a PWM method.

Comment: @joan I used `help(adafruit_servokit)` and `help(adafruit_pca9685)` and neither of those modules contain a class called `PWM`.

Comment: @Richard Wessels, Are you using this guide? https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-16-channel-pwm-servo-hat-for-raspberry-pi.pdf?timestamp=1565007378 The comment on page 14 of installing servo-kit makes me laugh: ... from your command line run the following command: sudo pip3 install adafruit-circuitpython-servokit, If your default Python is version 3 you may need to run 'pip' instead.

Comment: @Richard Wessels, I read the AdaFruit ServoHat/Bonnet user guide and found their Adafruit PCA9685 driver interesting.(1) Adafruit PCA9685 Driver Doc
https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/projects/pca9685/en/latest/api.html

(2)( Adafruit PCA9685 Driver Source
https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/projects/pca9685/en/latest/_modules/adafruit_pca9685.html#PCA9685  I am thinking of using this driver to do the PWM LED project described in Page 14 of the tutorial.  I have a cheapy TaoBao/AliExpress PCA9685 module which I think is software compatible with the expensive AdaFruit module.

Comment: @tlfong01 Yes, I am using that guide.

Comment: @Richard Wessels, I am going to use a cheapie board to try AdaFruit's PCA9685 driver.  First exercise: PWM a LED. AliExpress PCA9685 PWM/Servo Module for Raspberry Pi - US$ 1.98
https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/32753830158.html  Earlier I googled about AdaFruit servokit and have the feeling that the servokit may integrate their PWM driver to make a high level module which you can specify the servo angle, without bothering the details of PWM.  My goal is to drive servo and DC motor, both with PWM, so I am keen to go low level and try to play with PWM.

Comment: @Richard Wessels, In case you have not found out, the AdaFruit circuit-python packages/programs, including the PCA9685 python classes, are stored in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/.  You can "$ cd ~/.local ... " to find them.

Comment: @Richard Wessels, Now I am looking what circuitpython stuff is installed inside my ~/.local: https://imgur.com/0RKaixQ